# How to collapse a column in a longtable?

Tags: longtable, hide

There are various solutions to hide (not collapse) columns in tables, but not collapse. However, in a longtable they do not work.
Is there an other way to have tables spanning multiple pages neatly, AND have an easy solution to really collapsing columns, eg. by having an alignment option of 'H', as is customary?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\pdfinclusionerrorlevel = 1
\pdfminorversion = 7
\usepackage[
per-mode=symbol,
round-mode=places,
table-format = 1.2,
table-number-alignment=right,
% round-integer-to-decimal,
output-decimal-marker={.}
%scientific-notation=engineering
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{lHl} % does not work          
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{Fixations} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-3}          
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{A} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{B} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Units} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
        \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3}          
        \endfirsthead\caption{Fixations (Continued)}\\
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{F} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-3}          
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{A} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{B} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Units} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
        \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3}      
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{ Continued}
        \endfoot
        \endlastfoot
        $F_x$ & 6389 & \unit{\newton}\\
        $F_y$ & 0 & \unit{\newton}\\        
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume that an MWE would help with this question, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: Is not clear to me what you mean with "really collapsing columns" and what is the difference with hiding columns nor the purpose of shrink a column as it was in a black hole.  It is better if  you show a MWE  showing a table, and explain over it how  exactly X should  be changed to become Y  because Z (is advisable a screenshot of the goal, made in latex or not, if the desired result is hard to explain in few words). And then people can search the solution for Y, or better,  for Z.

Comment: hiding: the column would not be visible AND take its space.
collapse: he column would not be visible AND NOT take its space, so columns to its right would move left.

Comment: added MWE. Units column should move left.

Comment: Why `\multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell{Action}}` and not just simply `Action`?